# Javascript: Setting Z-Index on Multiple Elements (ID & Class)

Tags: javascript, z-index, layer

I have a javascript function that is supposed to hide and show layered divs by simply changing the z-index. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it works except for one issue. I have the content divs (absolutely positioned in CSS on top of each other), but I also have a navigation div (absolutely positioned in CSS at the bottom of the page) that should always remain on top. So I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var z = 1;
function showHide(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = z++;
document.getElementsByTagName('nav').style.zIndex = z++;
}
</script>
```

And I have this html:

```
<div id="1a" class="content" style="z-index:1;">Content</div>
<div id="1b" class="content">More Content</div>
<div id="1c" class="content">Even More Content</div>
<div class="nav" style="z-index:2;">
  <a href="#" onclick="showHide('1a')">1</a> 
| <a href="#" onclick="showHide('1b')">2</a> 
| <a href="#" onclick="showHide('1c')">3</a></div>
```

The problem is that the z-index line for the navigation div messes it up. Not only does it not execute, but anything I put after it doesn't get executed as well (even a basic alert). If I change navigation from a class to an id, it works fine, but I'm going to have multiple navigation divs on each page (multiple slides in a SlideDeck). I could just set the navigation div's z-index to 99999, but I wanted to see why it wasn't working in the "cleaner" way, since it looks like I might be making a basic mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but you need to create a loop for getElementsByTagName or getElementsByClassName:

```
var cells = table.getElementsByClassName('nav');
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.zIndex = z++;
}
```

Edit: Changed method call to getElementsByClassName. I initially just took what he wrote and added the loop.

Comment: getElementsByTagName takes tag names as arguments, not classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, arussell84, but that didn't quite fix it. I'm actually going to just put the nav div into each content div. That way, I can also easily deactivate the link for the active content div.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is that you are trying to use getElementsByTagName when you should be using [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName). [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) searches for elements based on tag name, like 'div' or 'span', not class names.

So, use it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var z = 1;
function showHide(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = z++;
  document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0].style.zIndex = z++;
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind that method was added in Firefox 3 and may not be supported in your browser. I would recommend using something like jQuery to maintain cross browser compatibility. Using jQuery, it would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var z = 1;
function showHide(id) {
  $('#'+id).style.zIndex = z++;
  $('.nav').style.zIndex = z++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, kcbanner. I wouldn't want to go with something that isn't universal, so I would probably try your second solution. However, like I said, I'm just going to include the nav in each content div. But I appreciate you letting me know what I was doing wrong.